# navigation not working in swiper using angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8, swiper.js

I am trying to use `swiper slider` but it's not navigating slide content.

Here is: [stackblitz - swiper](https://stackblitz.com/edit/swiper-angular-material-tabs-inside-tab-zj6txm) in last horizontal tab.

**ts:**

```
ngOnInit() {
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      slidesPerView: 1,
      spaceBetween: 50,
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
      breakpoints: {
        1024: {
          slidesPerView: 3,
          spaceBetween: 40,
        },
        768: {
          slidesPerView: 3,
          spaceBetween: 30,
        },
        640: {
          slidesPerView: 2,
          spaceBetween: 20,
        },
        320: {
          slidesPerView: 1,
          spaceBetween: 10,
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
        </div>
        <!-- Add Arrows -->
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  </div>
```

I am following this url: [swiperjs](https://swiperjs.com/get-started/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your swiper does not initialize on your `ngOnInit`

So,you can init swiper on tabChange

update your tab group with `selectedTabChange`

```
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="selectedIndex" (selectedTabChange)="onTabChange($event)">
```

and your ts file

like that

```
  onTabChange(event:any) {
    if (event.index === 2) {
      this.initSwiper();
    } 
  }

  initSwiper(){
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      slidesPerView: 1,
      spaceBetween: 50,
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
      breakpoints: {
        1024: {
          slidesPerView: 3,
          spaceBetween: 40,
        },
        768: {
          slidesPerView: 3,
          spaceBetween: 30,
        },
        640: {
          slidesPerView: 2,
          spaceBetween: 20,
        },
        320: {
          slidesPerView: 1,
          spaceBetween: 10,
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/swiper-angular-material-tabs-inside-tab-zj6txm-kxwgnu)